# Configuring Jenkins to run Main method Java Program or Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, junit

I have an application in Spring.

I am trying to configure Jenkins to run my Java Jobs from it. I am planning to have my Service Method's called from 
either
1. Java Class with Main method  /or/
2. Junit Test.

Next I was planning to configure the Java Program (with Main method) or the Junit Test as a Job from Jenkins. I guess I will need to add the Shell Script while configuring the Job.

I am stuck at the point where I cannot get the Spring dependencies resolved while running these programs from Jenkins. Is this approach even possible. I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? are you using nexus/artifactory/other?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera No, Everything is on my local machine as of now

Comment: have you a special maven settings in your local machine?